# Measurements - how they should be written in a list

Tags: numbers

Which is correct?

a. Images were obtained at a distance of **4, 8, 12, 16 and 20 mm** from the bottom of the plate.

b. Images were obtained at a distance of **4 mm, 8 mm, 12 mm, 16 mm and 20 mm** from the bottom of the plate.

c. Images were obtained at a distance of **4mm, 8mm, 12mm, 16mm and 20mm** from the bottom of the plate.

Comment: Does the style guide in your field (example: APA) say anything about this?

Comment: It really doesn’t matter. If this is for publication in a scientific journal the sub-editor will put it into house style. (Although I’m fairly sure that c will be changed to b.)

Comment: Also, if you have an Fig of this in your paper, consider writing something like “between 4 and 20 mm”. If all variants to sentence have problems, the answer is often to rewrite the sentence.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten some commas.

Answer (score 1):

The first two examples are acceptable. I prefer the first, but that's only an opinion.

The third is incorrect by most style guides I know. As an "authoritative" reference in case you don't have a specific style guide to follow, I'd cite the [NIST Guide for the Use of the International System of Units](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf), p 8:

> There is a space between the numerical value and unit symbol, even when the value is used as an adjective, except in the case of superscript units for plane angle. (See Sec. 7.2.)
>
> > a 25 kg sphere but not: a 25-kg sphere
> >
> > an angle of 2º3'4" but not: an angle of 2 º3 '4 "
>
> If the spelled-out name of a unit is used, the normal rules of English are applied: “a roll of
> 35-millimeter film.” (See Sec. 7.6, note 3.)

(Which is also interesting because the style guide for my college's theses called for a dash between number and unit when used as an adjective)

Comment: Dear 'The Photon' - this is so useful - thank you very much indeed.  And thank you as well for alerting me to the NIST Guide.  Really helpful.  Best regards, M-L Archer

Comment: There is a dash if the the numbers are spelled out: *A twenty-five-kilogram sphere.*